# Sort based on field on a very large file(270 gb)

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I am trying sort based on key value (6th field). The file is around 270 GB.

```
1|803684617|558888522818|12nbhmjggl|2018-07-07|0000012345|DIVIDED
1|803684617|558888522818|12nbhmjggl|2018-07-07|0000010501|busted
1|803684617|558888522818|12nbhmjggl|2018-07-07|0000012344|explosion
```

I tried this command

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 4,4 <filename>
```

I am getting  message as

```
sort: write failed: /tmp/sortzOWhwz: No space left on device
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have enough space left to store the temporary files created by the sort.

Comment: Yes correct... and solution for that?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use a bigger hard disk. Or you could write your own sorting/indexing routine, or split the file, sort the parts and merge them together with some code. Or just use a database to do the indexing for you.